# Windows 7 wildcard * not working

Tags: windows-7, search, windows-search

I am using Windows 7 wildcard search.

I am in a folder that contains a file called test.xml

In the top right search box I enter...

```
*.xml
```

And for some reason it find no files. This problem symptomizes regardless of the file extension

Comment: don't know, win7 file search is a bit rubbish.. some alternatives are agent ransack and the cmd prompt.. Also you should really google about windows 7 search not picking files up and what to do and try those things. One of the things can be if it  or that it, only searches what is indexed, so you have to add things to the index

Comment: I agree that Windows search has problems.  You shouldn't have to do this, but what do you get if you type `filename:*.xml`?

Comment: If you copy the file to your My Documents folder and do the search in that location does it work correctly?